# CSS slideout menu

Tags: html, css, menu, tabs

I am trying to adapt a pure css based slideout interface (typically used with texts and forms) to create a set of shortcut links, it should be fairly straight forward but for some reason there is a huge margin when the interface slides out.

Here is my [example,](http://jsfiddle.net/FUAQJ/840/) I may very well be missing the obvious, a little help please!

```
easier to click the example :)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#slideout_inner` has a fixed width of 200px, thats why there is so much space around the list `ul`.

if you want to keep using that width, you could align the text in the `ul` on the left.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FUAQJ/841/

The things I changed:

```
#slideout_inner ul {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you.. I have just updated the original question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to edit the css for fixing the issue, 
Please updated the below classes

```
#slideout_inner{ padding: 0px; width:242px;}
#slideout_inner textarea{ textarea: 241px; }
```

Comment: that just created a gap between the tab and the slideout content

Answer (score -1):

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/7rwme2py/)
you have Too many position and height on

```
 #slideout_inner
 #slideout
```

Comment: I have cleaned up your code. you have fixed position two time, take review of http://jsfiddle.net/mmz22zdg/2/